# Changing view via category with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a bookshop project I was trying to change the books viewed according to their category and I'm totally lost I'm an absolute beginner and this is my first web project ever and I really need help.

This is my `Book` model class:

```
using BookStore1.Models.Comments;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BookStore1.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Author { get; set; } = "Unknown";
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string? imageURL { get; set; }
        public List<MainComment>? MainComments { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? Image { set; get; }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Category` model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BookStore1.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Book>? Books { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

How can make a view with dropdown list with categories and when I choose a category the books it has are viewed? I don't need a full answer or a code to copy I just need someone to set me on the right path.

Thank you.

Comment: See [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-search-by-genre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set a `onchange()` method in the DropdownList, Then when user select a Category , Ajax will send the Id of Category to post method, In post method, you can select the books by  CategoryId and return books to page, Finally. I wrote a simple demo to show my method in more detail.

**controller**

```
//For testing convenience, I just hard code here
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category()
            {
                Id = 1,
                CategoryName = "TypeA"
            },
            new Category()
            {
                Id = 2,
                CategoryName = "TypeB"
            }
            
        };

        List<Book> books = new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "BookA",
                Author = "AuthorA",
                CategoryId = 1,
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "BookAA",
                Author = "AuthorAA",
                CategoryId = 1,
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "BookB",
                Author = "AuthorB",
                CategoryId = 2,
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "BookAAA",
                Author = "AuthorAAA",
                CategoryId = 1,
            }
        };

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //set the dropdownlist
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach(var item in categories)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem() {Value = item.Id.ToString(),Text = item.CategoryName });
            }
            //use viewbag to pass the dropdownlist from controller to view
            ViewBag.book = list;
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int ID)
        {
            //select books by CategoryId
            var result = books.Where(x => x.CategoryId == ID).ToList();
            return Json(result);
        }
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="control-label"> Choose Category</label>

                <select name="products" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.book" onchange="select(this.value)"></select>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="text-center" id="Test"></div>
  
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function select(Id){
           
            var data = {
                'ID' : Id
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/index",
                data: data,              
                success: function (res) { 
                     result = '';
                  for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ){
                      result = result +'<tr><td>'+res[i].name+'</td><td>'+res[i].author+'</td></tr>';
                  }  
                        
                    
                    document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable" role="grid">'
                                                                 +'<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Author</th></tr></thead>'                                                                
                                                                 +'<tbody>'+result+'</tbody>'
                                                                 +'</table>';
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

**I hope it is what you want.**